# How to get play-2.3-highlights activator template working?

Tags: playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I am creating a new application using the [play-2.3-highlights](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-2.3-highlights) activator template.

```
activator new play-2.3-highlights play-2.3-highlights
```

It successfully creates new application.

However when I run `activator run` in the `play-2.3-highlights` directory I get the following error:

```
[debug] application - Unforseen error for Controller.js at /public
```

But it is available from browser - opening `http://localhost:9000/assets/javascripts/Controller.js` gives me the javascript. `main.js` is also near `Controller.js`.

What can be a solution for the issue?

Comment: It worked fine for me. I have never worked with the template before so I'd exclude the possibility that I had the dependencies pulled down. Could you set up the application using the template again (note how I changed the command in your question)? Attach the entire logs from `activator run` to the question. Do you have activator installed? What about the version of Java? What's the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it work I updated main.coffee paths from:

```
page: "./Page"
controller: "./controller"
sumWebSocket: "./SumWebSocket"
jquery: "../lib/jquery/jquery"
```

to

```
page: "./javascripts/Page"
controller: "./javascripts/controller"
sumWebSocket: "./javascripts/SumWebSocket"
jquery: "./lib/jquery/jquery"
```

main.coffee is also in javascripts folder near all other scripts, not sure why I need to specify javascripts folders